# What's the point of NSRange.toRange()?

Tags: swift, range, nsrange

[Apple's Swift documentation for `String.UTF16View`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string.utf16view) says:

> Use the `NSRange` type’s `toRange` method to convert [an `NSRange`] instance to an optional range of `Int` values.

What's the point of the `NSRange` type’s `toRange` method? And, why would it ever return `nil`?

Why not just use the `NSRange`'s `location` to get `lowerBound` and `NSMaxRange(_:)` to get `upperBound`?

For example, given

```
let nsrange = NSRange(location: 3, length: 12)
```

instead of

```
let r = nsrange.toRange()
```

why not just do

```
let lowerBound = nsrange.location
let upperBound = NSMaxRange(nsrange)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the Swift source code for the `NSRange` type’s `toRange` method implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSRange.swift#L159-L163).

```
public func toRange() -> Range<Int>? {
    if location == NSNotFound { return nil }
    return location..<(location+length)
}
```

As you suspected, the method uses the `NSRange`'s `location` to get `lowerBound` and `location+length`, which is equivalent to `NSMaxRange(_:)`, to get `upperBound`. It returns `nil` if the the `NSRange`'s `location` is `NSNotFound`.

Note: As of Swift 4, this method has been deprecated and has been renamed to `Range.init(_:)`.

Comment: FYI, that's a dead link.